# The implicit differentiation of trignometry equations

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Use the process of implicit differentiation to find $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$

given that  $\sin(x)+ \sin(3y) = 1 $

Can anyone give me hints or steps on what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the implicit derivative confuses you then think of both $x$ and $y$ being functions of $t$ and take $\dfrac{d}{dt}$ of both sides:

\begin{equation}
\cos(x)\dfrac{dx}{dt}+3\cos(3y)\dfrac{dy}{dt}=0
\end{equation}

Then rewrite as

\begin{equation}
\cos(x)\,dx+3\cos(3y)\,dy=0
\end{equation}

And solve to obtain

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{dx}{dy}=-\dfrac{3\cos(3y)}{\cos(x)}
\end{equation}

Comment: Than you so much and for the tip of thinking of it as t, I struggle with implicit derivative and this has helped me so much thank you/

Comment: I accidentally solved for $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ instead of $\dfrac{dx}{dy}$ as you asked but have corrected that.